# Pass data from activity back to already created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

Bank app:

I have a NavigationDrawerActivity which has more fragments. Each fragment is created after menu item is clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_transfer) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TransferFragment()).commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I click on "transfer" menu item, TransferFragment is created. This fragment is responsible for simple money transferring from one bank account to another. I have a "choose account" button in this fragment which **starts (using intent) new activity - ChooseAccountActivity**. This activity is just a listView containing all accounts which can be used to transfer the money from.

After the user clicks on one of the accounts, the accountId (String) should be sent **BACK** to TransferFragment so the user is able to continue filling up other EditTexts (amount, receiver's account id, etc.)

method in "ChooseAccountActivity":

```
public void eventAfterClickOnListViewItem() {
    accountsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String accountId = allAccountsList.get(position);
            //PASS accountId back to TransferFragment
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

So I need to send **the data (accountId)** back to TransferFragment. But Intent doesn't work because I work with fragment. The TransferFragment is already created so only onStart, onResume,.. is called after coming back to the fragment.

Any tip or advice how I can pass the data from the activity to the already created fragment? Am I doing this right or should I change my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult` in your TransferFragment to start ChooseAccountActivity and override `onActivityResult` at TransferFragment to get the accountId.
Make sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment) to get the results in your fragment.